# How to disable a button after it is clicked a certain number of times?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm making a game similar to 'who wants to be a millionaire?' and I have a 'Next' button which takes the player to the next question. However, since I am allowing up to four players to play, I want this 'Next' button to disable after a maximum of 3 clicks, (or less if there is one/two/three players playing).

Here is my code so far for the 'Next' button:

```
nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            StatusPage.setVisible(false);
            QuestionPage.setVisible(true);
            option1.setEnabled(true);
            option2.setEnabled(true);
            option3.setEnabled(true);
            option4.setEnabled(true);

            if (Player2JButton.isEnabled()){
                counter = 1;
            }
            else if (Player3JButton.isEnabled()){
                counter = 2;
            }
            else if (Player4JButton.isEnabled()){
                counter = 3;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Error getting next question.");
            }

            if (generalKnowledge.isEnabled()){

                currentQuest = quest.setQnA(option1, option2, option3, option4, question1, "generalKnowledge");
            }
            else if (geography.isEnabled()){

                currentQuest = quest.setQnA(option1, option2, option3, option4, question1, "geography");
            }
            else if (hipHopMusic.isEnabled()){

                currentQuest = quest.setQnA(option1, option2, option3, option4, question1, "hipHopMusic");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Error getting next question.");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried using a for loop but I couldn't figure out how to use that for my purpose so I left it.

Comment: you should include what you've tried. and to ask the obvious, you've tried a counter of sorts?

Comment: `private int counter;`, every time someone clicks, you increment `counter` within the `actionPerformed`-block. If counter is greater than 2, it's been clicked 3 times, disable `nextButton` with `#setEnabled`.

Comment: add it to the question, please/ it's not readable in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about using a simple int variable that will count the number of times one of the players pressed that button?

What do you think about this:

```
    final int NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS=4;
    int count=0;



     nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                count++; 
                if(count-1==NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS) 
                  {
                  nextButton.setEnabled(false);  //disable the button
                  }

              ///Your code

            }
        });
```

Comment: I just tried using this @yoav, could you please explain what the if (count-1==NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS) statement does? As I'm a little confused on how to use it.

Comment: the (count-1==NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS) statement is vary simple; its make the button to disable according to the number of players. I added this because you mentioned in you question that the button should be disable by the number of players. Examples:  if the number of player are four the button will be disable after three presses. If the number of players are three, the button will be disable after two presses and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'll add it as an answer. Here's a working sample, without some Android-yitter.

We'll use an `int counter`. Every time someone clicks you increment counter within the `actionPerformed`-block. If `counter` is greater than 2, it's been clicked 3 times. We'll disable `nextButton` with `#setEnabled`.

```
public class ButtonCycle extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private int counter = 0;
    private JButton btn;

    public ButtonCycle() {
        this.btn = new JButton("Next");
        this.btn.addActionListener(this);

        add(this.btn);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Button cycling through animations");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,250));
                f.setContentPane(new ButtonCycle());
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        switch(this.counter) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
                this.counter++;
                break;
            case 2:
                ((JButton) a.getSource()).setEnabled(false);
                // or like this
                this.btn.setEnabled(false);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Should give you what you need.

Comment: Please do not just throw code on screen. Explain what you did and how your answer resolves the question.

Comment: I'll add what I wrote in the comments for you.

Comment: How about editing your answer. Look below your answer, to the left.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't up to your standards on speed; I was already editing the answer, and you should see it by now (in fact, before you posted your comment).

Comment: You're not here to meet my standards. The heavy traffic on Stack Overflow is due to the quality of the answers provided, so if you're going to post here, accept the constructive criticism of people who have been down this road before. I'm trying to help you be better, so kindly stow the passive aggressive BS.